# Messed up bash.bashrc file, can not access Azure VM using SSH anymore

Tags: azure, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I was doing some changes in the `bashrc` file. After trying to reload the file again I was logged out of the SSH session and now I am not able to access it anymore. I tried to restart the VM but ofc this did not solve my issue. Since I am new to Azure cloud any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try VM Serial Console to get into your VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/serial-console-overview